# C++ Object creation difference

Tags: c++

Sorry I know this is a really basic question but it's something that keeps tripping me up in my code. Can someone please (as simple as possible) explain to me the difference in writing:

```
a* objName;
```

versus

```
a* objName = new a();
```

I keep thinking that it's functionally the same, other than dynamic/automatic memory allocation, but it seems the way I use objName is different based on which of the above I write.

Thank you

Comment: `a* objName;` is an uninitialized pointer, so reading or writing to `*objName` causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Did you mean your first example to be `a objName;`, in other words create an actual object and not just an uninitialized pointer? Your question text sounds like this is the case.

Comment: No @hyde. From the answers I've realised I was getting those confused as well. Very new to C++ so pointers have been a bit difficult to wrap my head around

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using *either* one of those constructs!  Both are much better handled by writing C++ code, not C-style code in C++.

Instead of

```
a* objName;
```

you should write

```
std::unique_ptr<a> objName;
```

Although perhaps `a* objName` is a typo and you *actually* meant to write

```
a objName;
```

If so, this creates an instance of `a` on the stack as opposed to allocating dynamic memory.

And instead of

```
a* objName = new a();
```

You should use `std::make_unique`.

```
auto objName = std::make_unique<a>();
```

Adopting such habits now will make your C++ development life **much** easier.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the difference between

```
int x;
```

and

```
int x = 42;
```

They both declare a local variable, but the first leaves the value *uninitialized* while the latter sets it to 42.

Same thing for the code in your question: the first declares a pointer but does not assign it a value (ie a memory location of an `a` value), while the latter initializes it with the expression `new a()` which constructs an `a` value on the heap and returns the address.

Answer (score 2):

Both versions declare a pointer. In the first the pointer is uninitialised so using it is likely to crash your program. In the second the pointer is made to point to a dynamically allocated object.

If at a later stage you initialise the pointer declared the first version then you would use it in exactly the same way as the second version.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> a* objName;
> ```

This creates an automatic - or static depending on context - object of type `a*`. The object is default initialised, which in case of a pointer type means that there is no initialisation. In the case the variable has static storage, it will be zero initialised, which for pointer means it will point to null. In case it is automatic, the value will be indeterminate.

If you attempt to indirect through this pointer to access the non-existing object, the behaviour of the program will be undefined.

> ```
> a* objName = new a();
> ```

This also creates an automatic or static, depending on context, object of type `a*`. The difference is that in this case it is initialised.

Besides that, this also creates a dynamic object of type `a`. The pointer is initialised to point to the dynamic object. The dynamic object is value initialised.

Accessing the object through the pointer has well defined behaviour. Losing the pointer value without using `delete` on it will cause a memory leak.

P.S. Don't use owning bare pointers. Instead, use RAII containers such as smart pointers for dynamic allocation. Also, avoid dynamic allocation when you don't need it.